# How can I copy and paste transitions in Hitfilm 4 Express?

Tags: video-editor

I'm editing a project in Hitfilm's timeline editor and was hoping there would be a faster way to apply the same transition to the beginning and end of several images. Can I copy/paste/sync/apply to all?

[image]